Editors crashing with certain characters, programs crashing, how to diagnoze?
I'm having strange problems with my PC and don't know what to do. It all started with the fact that certain characters (Devanagari characters) could no longer be displayed in my Emacs. Whenever I opened a document containing these characters and then scrolled to the place where the characters were supposed to be displayed, Emacs closed automatically.
An error is then logged in the Linux Mint system reports, if I want to call it up, then this programme also closes. I have tried everything possible. It is not due to my Emacs config.
Firefox or Thunderbird also crashes now and then. But I don't know exactly what causes them.
I bought new RAM but also RAM is not causing the issue.
I figured out how to access the respective crash report, and it says (dmesg):
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.437715] ata2.00:  exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x80 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.437722] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.437726] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.437733] ata2.00: cmd 60/08:38:58:01:17/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq dma 4096 in
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.437733]          res 41/40:00:58:01:17/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.437736] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.437739] ata2.00: error: { UNC }
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.443486] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.443504] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.443507] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.443509] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.443512] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 17 01 58 00 00 08 00
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.443515] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1507672 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.443540] ata2: EH complete
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.485670] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.485675] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.485679] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.485684] ata2.00: cmd 60/08:60:58:01:17/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 12 ncq dma 4096 in
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.485684]          res 41/40:00:58:01:17/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.485687] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.485689] ata2.00: error: { UNC }
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.491673] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.491691] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.491696] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.491699] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.491703] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 17 01 58 00 00 08 00
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.491707] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1507672 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 kernel: [ 1272.491739] ata2: EH complete
Apr  9 17:29:01 enjotel-mint20 systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 6655/UID 0).
Apr  9 17:29:02 enjotel-mint20 systemd-coredump[6656]: Process 6620 (emacs28) of user 1000 dumped core.#012#012Stack trace of thread 6620:#012#0  0x00007f4758af12ab raise (libpthread.so.0 + 0x142ab)#012#1  0x0000000000426a3d n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x26a3d)#012#2  0x0000000000426efc n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x26efc)#012#3  0x000000000052eecd n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x12eecd)#012#4  0x000000000052efbf n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x12efbf)#012#5  0x00007f4758af1420 __restore_rt (libpthread.so.0 + 0x14420)#012#6  0x00007f4758d280f0 n/a (libotf.so.0 + 0xb0f0)#012#7  0x00007f4758d2a013 OTF_get_features (libotf.so.0 + 0xd013)#012#8  0x00007f4758d2a078 OTF_check_features (libotf.so.0 + 0xd078)#012#9  0x000000000060ba72 n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x20ba72)#012#10 0x00000000005af03c n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x1af03c)#012#11 0x00000000005af9d8 n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x1af9d8)#012#12 0x0000000000610859 n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x210859)#012#13 0x00000000006110db n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x2110db)#012#14 0x00000000006115f9 n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x2115f9)#012#15 0x00000000005ae249 n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x1ae249)#012#16 0x00000000005fa4be n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x1fa4be)#012#17 0x00000000005fc793 n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x1fc793)#012#18 0x00000000005fd518 n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x1fd518)#012#19 0x00000000005268cd n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x1268cd)#012#20 0x00000000005942e7 n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x1942e7)#012#21 0x000000000051650a n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x11650a)#012#22 0x0000000000594229 n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x194229)#012#23 0x00000000005164a6 n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x1164a6)#012#24 0x000000000051be50 n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x11be50)#012#25 0x000000000051c1a6 n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x11c1a6)#012#26 0x000000000042e465 n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x2e465)#012#27 0x00007f4758751083 __libc_start_main (libc.so.6 + 0x24083)#012#28 0x000000000042eb3e n/a (emacs-28.128 + 0x2eb3e)#012#012Stack trace of thread 6623:#012#0  0x00007f475883fbbf __GI___poll (libc.so.6 + 0x112bbf)#012#1  0x00007f475fa0f36e n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x5236e)#012#2  0x00007f475fa0f4a3 g_main_context_iteration (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x524a3)#012#3  0x00007f475fa0f4f1 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x524f1)#012#4  0x00007f475fa38ae1 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x7bae1)#012#5  0x00007f4758ae5609 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x8609)#012#6  0x00007f475884c353 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x11f353)#012#012Stack trace of thread 6624:#012#0  0x00007f475883fbbf __GI___poll (libc.so.6 + 0x112bbf)#012#1  0x00007f475fa0f36e n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x5236e)#012#2  0x00007f475fa0f6f3 g_main_loop_run (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x526f3)#012#3  0x00007f475fc6bf8a n/a (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0x11ef8a)#012#4  0x00007f475fa38ae1 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x7bae1)#012#5  0x00007f4758ae5609 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x8609)#012#6  0x00007f475884c353 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x11f353)#012#012Stack trace of thread 6625:#012#0  0x00007f475883fbbf __GI___poll (libc.so.6 + 0x112bbf)#012#1  0x00007f475fa0f36e n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x5236e)#012#2  0x00007f475fa0f4a3 g_main_context_iteration (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x524a3)#012#3  0x00007f47528ef99d n/a (libdconfsettings.so + 0xa99d)#012#4  0x00007f475fa38ae1 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x7bae1)#012#5  0x00007f4758ae5609 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x8609)#012#6  0x00007f475884c353 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x11f353)
Apr  9 17:29:02 enjotel-mint20 systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@3-6655-0.service: Succeeded.

This is the result of enjotel@enjotel-mint20:~$ sudo smartctl -x /dev/sdb:
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-176-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Marvell based SanDisk SSDs
Device Model:     SanDisk SSD PLUS 1000GB
Serial Number:    20504Z800982
LU WWN Device Id: 5 001b44 8be8fa562
Firmware Version: UH5100RL
User Capacity:    1.000.207.286.272 bytes [1,00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Apr  9 18:35:18 2024 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM level is:     254 (maximum performance)
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]
Wt Cache Reorder: Unavailable

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x15) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Abort Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 182) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
 5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
 9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   100   100   000    -    9891
12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1411
165 Total_Write/Erase_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1774
166 Min_W/E_Cycle           -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    5
167 Min_Bad_Block/Die       -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    0
168 Maximum_Erase_Cycle     -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    26
169 Total_Bad_Block         -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    1501
170 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    0
171 Program_Fail_Count      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
173 Avg_Write/Erase_Count   -O--CK   100   100   000    -    5
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  -O--CK   100   100   000    -    20
184 End-to-End_Error        -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    11155
188 Command_Timeout         -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    0
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   073   054   000    -    27 (Min/Max 2/54)
199 SATA_CRC_Error          -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    0
230 Perc_Write/Erase_Count  -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1286 256 1286
232 Perc_Avail_Resrvd_Space PO--CK   100   100   005    -    100
233 Total_NAND_Writes_GiB   -O--CK   100   100   ---    -    5636
234 Perc_Write/Erase_Ct_BC  -O--CK   100   100   000    -    27722
241 Total_Writes_GiB        ----CK   100   100   000    -    11337
242 Total_Reads_GiB         ----CK   100   100   000    -    12756
244 Thermal_Throttle        -O--CK   000   100   ---    -    0
                           ||||||_ K auto-keep
                           |||||__ C event count
                           ||||___ R error rate
                           |||____ S speed/performance
                           ||_____ O updated online
                           |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      1  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O     16  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa1       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xa2       GPL,SL  VS       2  Device vendor specific log
0xa3-0xa4  GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xa7       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xa9       GPL,SL  VS       3  Device vendor specific log

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (16 sectors) Device
Error Count: 11155 (device log contains only the most recent 64
errors)     CR     = Command Register   FEATR  = Features Register  COUNT 
= Count (was: Sector Count) Register    LBA_48 = Upper bytes of LBA High/Mid/Low Registers ]  ATA-8     LH     = LBA High (was: Cylinder
High) Register    ]   LBA   LM     = LBA Mid (was: Cylinder Low)
Register      ] Register    LL     = LBA Low (was: Sector Number)
Register     ]  DV     = Device (was: Device/Head) Register     DC     =
Device Control Register     ER     = Error register     ST     = Status
register Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes, SS=sec, and
sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 11155 [4] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9890 hours (412
days + 2 hours)   When the command that caused the error occurred, the
device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:   ER -- ST COUNT 
LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC   -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --   40
-- 51 00 00 00 00 6b b4 7c 6c a0 00  Error: UNC

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:   CR
FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time 
Command/Feature_Name   -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- -- 
---------------  --------------------   2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:58.722  READ LOG EXT   ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 a0 00     02:05:58.667  FLUSH CACHE EXT   ea 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 a0 00     02:05:49.830  FLUSH CACHE EXT   2f 00 00 00 01
00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.826  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00
01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.781  READ LOG EXT

Error 11154 [3] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9890 hours (412
days + 2 hours)   When the command that caused the error occurred, the
device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:   ER -- ST COUNT 
LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC   -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --   40
-- 51 00 00 00 00 6b b4 7c 6c a0 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:   CR
FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time 
Command/Feature_Name   -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- -- 
---------------  --------------------   ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00     02:05:58.667  FLUSH CACHE EXT   ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 a0 00     02:05:49.830  FLUSH CACHE EXT   2f 00 00 00 01 00
00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.826  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00 01
00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.781  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00
01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.721  READ LOG EXT

Error 11153 [2] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9890 hours (412
days + 2 hours)   When the command that caused the error occurred, the
device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:   ER -- ST COUNT 
LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC   -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --   40
-- 51 00 28 00 00 6b b4 7c 94 a0 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:   CR
FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time 
Command/Feature_Name   -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- -- 
---------------  --------------------   ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00     02:05:49.830  FLUSH CACHE EXT   2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.826  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00 01 00 00
00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.781  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00 01 00
00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.721  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00 01
00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.666  READ LOG EXT

Error 11152 [1] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9890 hours (412
days + 2 hours)   When the command that caused the error occurred, the
device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:   ER -- ST COUNT 
LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC   -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --   40
-- 51 00 00 00 00 6b b4 7c 6c a0 00  Error: UNC

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:   CR
FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time 
Command/Feature_Name   -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- -- 
---------------  --------------------   2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.826  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00
08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.781  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.721  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00 01 00 00
00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.666  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00 01 00
00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.621  READ LOG EXT

Error 11151 [0] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9890 hours (412
days + 2 hours)   When the command that caused the error occurred, the
device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:   ER -- ST COUNT 
LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC   -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --   40
-- 51 00 00 00 00 6b b4 7c 6c a0 00  Error: UNC

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:   CR
FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time 
Command/Feature_Name   -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- -- 
---------------  --------------------   2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.781  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00
08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.721  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.666  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00 01 00 00
00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.621  READ LOG EXT   2f 00 00 00 01 00
00 00 00 08 30 a0 00     02:05:28.566  READ LOG EXT

Warning! SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Structure error:
invalid SMART checksum. Error 11150 [63] occurred at disk power-on
lifetime: 61166 hours (2548 days + 14 hours)   When the command that
caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:   ER -- ST COUNT 
LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC   -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --   00
-- 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:   CR
FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time 
Command/Feature_Name   -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- -- 
---------------  --------------------   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 45 16d+13:40:55.765  NOP [Abort queued commands]   00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 44 13d+06:08:44.612  NOP [Abort queued
commands]   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 43  9d+22:36:33.459 
NOP [Abort queued commands]   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 42 
6d+15:04:22.306  NOP [Abort queued commands]   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 41  3d+07:32:11.153  NOP [Abort queued commands]

Error 11149 [62] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 61166 hours (2548
days + 14 hours)   When the command that caused the error occurred,
the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:   ER -- ST COUNT 
LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC   -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --   00
-- 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:   CR
FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time 
Command/Feature_Name   -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- -- 
---------------  --------------------   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 35 16d+13:40:55.765  NOP [Abort queued commands]   00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 34 13d+06:08:44.612  NOP [Abort queued
commands]   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 33  9d+22:36:33.459 
NOP [Abort queued commands]   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 32 
6d+15:04:22.306  NOP [Abort queued commands]   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 31  3d+07:32:11.153  NOP [Abort queued commands]

Error 11148 [61] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 61166 hours (2548
days + 14 hours)   When the command that caused the error occurred,
the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:   ER -- ST COUNT 
LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC   -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --   00
-- 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:   CR
FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time 
Command/Feature_Name   -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- -- 
---------------  --------------------   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 25 16d+13:40:55.765  NOP [Abort queued commands]   00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 13d+06:08:44.612  NOP [Abort queued
commands]   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 23  9d+22:36:33.459 
NOP [Abort queued commands]   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 22 
6d+15:04:22.306  NOP [Abort queued commands]   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 21  3d+07:32:11.153  NOP [Abort queued commands]

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors) No self-tests have
been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported

SCT Commands not supported

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04) Page  Offset Size        Value Flags
Description 0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics
(rev 1) == 0x01  0x008  4            1411  ---  Lifetime Power-On
Resets 0x01  0x010  4            9891  ---  Power-on Hours 0x01  0x018
6     23777035689  ---  Logical Sectors Written 0x01  0x028  6    
26752324966  ---  Logical Sectors Read 0x01  0x038  6            9891 
---  Date and Time TimeStamp 0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) == 0x05  0x008  1              27  --- 
Current Temperature 0x05  0x010  1               -  ---  Average Short
Term Temperature 0x05  0x018  1               -  ---  Average Long
Term Temperature 0x05  0x020  1              53  ---  Highest
Temperature 0x05  0x028  1              13  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x05  0x030  1              27  ---  Highest Average Short Term
Temperature 0x05  0x038  1              27  ---  Lowest Average Short
Term Temperature 0x05  0x040  1               -  ---  Highest Average
Long Term Temperature 0x05  0x048  1               -  ---  Lowest
Average Long Term Temperature 0x05  0x050  4               0  --- 
Time in Over-Temperature 0x05  0x058  1              95  --- 
Specified Maximum Operating Temperature 0x05  0x060  4               0
---  Time in Under-Temperature 0x05  0x068  1               0  ---  Specified Minimum Operating Temperature 0x07  =====  =               =
===  == Solid State Device Statistics (rev 1) == 0x07  0x008  1               1  N--  Percentage Used Endurance Indicator
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

Pending Defects log (GP Log 0x0c) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11) ID      Size     Value 
Description 0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host
data FIS 0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device
data FIS 0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host
non-data FIS 0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device
non-data FIS 0x0009  2           43  Transition from drive PhyRdy to
drive PhyNRdy 0x000a  2           44  Device-to-host register FISes
sent due to a COMRESET 0x000f  2            0  R_ERR response for
host-to-device data FIS, CRC 0x0012  2            0  R_ERR response
for host-to-device non-data FIS, CRC 0x0001  2            0  Command
failed due to ICRC error


I solved the issue regarding the boot. In my BIOS I had fast boot activated. Upon deactivation I can open my other operating systems. In my older Linux distribution emacs and the rest operates smoothly without issues. So the only problem that remains is that those problems keep crashing. Particularly Emacs once I enter Devanagari characters into the window, the buffer shuts down. I get a crash error in System reports and once I want to open that also this one crashes.

The messages in the crash report indicate that the sdb disk had a read error and returned bad data. It says auto reallocate failed, so it might be that any spare capacity to replace detected bad blocks is already used up.
You should run sudo smartctl -x /dev/sdb and see what it reports.
Also, you should definitely keep your backups up to date, in case the sdb disk suddenly dies completely (as failing SSDs sometimes do).

Your disk is dying, data has to be carved up, and disk replaced ASAP.

If you try and fail data recovery using GNU ddrescue (gddrescue package in Debian/Ubuntu repositories), and presuming you would need the data from this failing disk, please contact some reputable data recovery centre.

There is nothing you can do with software or hardware to revert this SATA SSD damage, total failure is imminent.


